Unable to Delete Class Code in Flask Application
I'm working on a Flask application where I need to delete class codes from the database using a DELETE request. I'm using JavaScript on the front-end to trigger the deletion, and I have a Flask route set up to handle the request. However, I am unable to delete the class code when the button is clicked. Here's the code I've written:
Front-End (JavaScript & HTML):
<!-- Example button for deleting a class code -->
<button class="delete-btn" data-id="{{ class_code.id }}">Delete</button>

<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.delete-btn').forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        let classCodeId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
        
        fetch(`/delete_class_code/${classCodeId}`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                // Include additional headers if needed, such as CSRF token for security
            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.message === 'Class code deleted successfully!') {
                // Optionally remove the element from the DOM
                this.closest('.class-code-item').remove();
                alert('Class code deleted!');
            } else {
                alert('Failed to delete class code!');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    });
});
</script>

Flask Route:
@main.route('/delete_class_code/<int:id>', methods=['DELETE'])
@login_required
def delete_class_code(id):
    if current_user.role != 'employee':
        return jsonify({'message': 'Unauthorized'}), 403

    try:
        # Assuming you have a ClassCode model and you're using SQLAlchemy
        class_code = ClassCode.query.get(id)
        if class_code:
            db.session.delete(class_code)
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'message': 'Class code deleted successfully!'}), 200
        return jsonify({'message': 'Class code not found.'}), 404
    except Exception as e:
        db.session.rollback()  # Ensure the session is rolled back if there is an error
        return jsonify({'message': 'An error occurred: ' + str(e)}), 500

Issue:

When I click the "Delete" button, the class code does not get deleted, and the message "Failed to delete class code!" is shown.
I suspect the issue may be related to how the Flask route is handling the request, or there may be an issue with how the front-end is making the DELETE request.

What I’ve Tried:

I have confirmed that the front-end is sending the DELETE request properly.
I’ve checked the Flask route, and it seems to be handling the request correctly, but the class code is not being deleted.
On the Flask side, I’ve added exception handling and session rollback, but no error messages are shown in the browser’s console.
I’ve ensured the CSRF token is sent correctly in the request headers.

What I Was Expecting:

I was expecting the class code to be deleted when I click the "Delete" button and for the front-end to update the list of class codes accordingly.
I also expected the success message "Class code deleted successfully!" to appear, and for the class code to be removed from the DOM.

Could someone help me identify where the issue might be or suggest any improvements?
Thanks in advance!

You can try to debug a whole response ( a returned code, the data, etc.) on the front-end side.
Maybe your code is failed on this part?
if current_user.role != 'employee':         return jsonify({'message': 'Unauthorized'}), 403

Quick suggestion: look at the status code, rather than the text to determine if the call succeeded. The status code will remain stable, while the text could change. What happens if you call the route in your browser, without JS? This could be a CORS issue or something else. Use the logging module inside your function to output debug info. Why not use console.log in your JS function to output the actual response you are getting?

yeah the result after I debug is 2024-12-26 01:52:21,054 - INFO - 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2024 01:52:21] "DELETE /delete_class_code/undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 - and Iam really stuck at this

I have run the code that you posted within my own flask server with Chrome as the client and have observed different behavior. this.getAttribute('data-id') worked as intended and the delete url was constructed correctly. Are you certain that the code you have posted here is the code that you are actually running and if so what browser are you using?

@EAW of course is certain actually running and I am using Chrome's latest version

In that case I cannot explain why your code runs as intended on my machine yet fails on yours. The only other thing I can think of trying is to use event.target rather than this to obtain a reference to the button that your event handler is bound to as this is where your code appears to fail.

@EAW let me try in my code first okay
